# Indexing and Sorting a UITableView with Values Parsed from an XML by Date

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, sorting, nsdictionary

I am parsing an `XML` file from a URL, from this `XML` I parse titles of events, their dates, and locations of the events among other things. These elements are cached in an array called `stories` which acts as my data source for my table view. My goal is to display and indexed `UITableView` with the sections based on the date at which my events take place by month (January's events in a section, February's events in another, with month names as the titles for my sections). The events that will take place soonest will be at the top of my view, events further out should be at the bottom of my list, I don't have to worry about events that have already taken place. So far I've been able to display my event names and their dates as subtitles in my UITableView not sorted or indexed, left in the order by which they were parsed. When I log the `stories` array I view this in the console:

```
2013-01-04 00:17:22.332 NumberTwo[72213:c07] the stories array is as follows: (
    {
    additionalDesc = "";
    allday = "Yes.";
    endtime = "11:55 PM";
    isodate = "2013-05-23";
    location = "";
    starttime = "12:00 AM";
    title = "CST Exam Makeups";
},
    {
    additionalDesc = "";
    allday = "No.";
    endtime = "12:00 PM";
    isodate = "2013-06-01";
    location = "";
    starttime = "8:00 AM";
    title = "SAT & Subject Tests";
},)
```

There is an example of two elements in the array, I understand I am going to have break down the `stories` array into smaller ones based on the month that the events occur but I don't know what that method would look like. Here's my attempt at it in the `viewDidLoad`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.sections = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (UIEvent *event in stories)
{

    NSDate *dateRepresentingThisDay = tempDate;

    // If we don't yet have an array to hold the events for this day, create one
    NSMutableArray *eventsOnThisDay = [self.sections objectForKey:dateRepresentingThisDay];
    if (eventsOnThisDay == nil) {
        eventsOnThisDay = [NSMutableArray array];

    }

    // Add the event to the list for this day
    [eventsOnThisDay addObject:event];
}

// Create a sorted list of days
NSArray *unsortedDays = [self.sections allKeys];
self.sortedDays = [unsortedDays sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

}

I know the line `for (UIEvent *event in stories)` must be incorrect but I'm sure what should replace it. `tempDate` is a formatted date I receive from an `NSDateFormatter` in another method, and `event` is meant to refer to an element in my array `stories`. If you could, point me in the right direction to accomplish my goal, it would be much appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have to use the following steps:
1. On the number of section method of table view write the array count.
2. you also have to modify your array by comparing the dates which are available on stack overflow and arrange in array according to your requirement.
3. Set title by giving title.text = [your array object at index[index path of section]]
4. Now you can give rows as you like in it.

This are just steps you need to follow..
Have you got what I mean to say?

Comment: I understand the steps necessary to achieve my goal, thank you for the thorough answer, but I'm still having trouble with what the fast enumeration for statement would like, I can see debugging that my code below the for statement isnt being called

Comment: So in this case you should try to find sample code for all the steps one by one and integrate them finally.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you create a class for the above data and have NSDate property to represent your start date/time of the event? If so, you can make use of NSPredicate to sort the array based on your start date property. You can find details on NSPredicate on this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-250409).